# I want to concatenate df2 to under C columns of df1, and making df3 with all columns of df1 and df2

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, concatenation, append

This is df1

```
AWB/AWBCreated Date  Status AWB/AWB Number  AWB/Sender/Name AWB/Sender/Mobile
2024-02-13 00:00:00  Open   5449151CGT          phoe la pyae    9797116597
2024-02-13 00:00:00  Open   5449127AVE          Zin Lin *** 9441450256
2024-02-13 00:00:00  Open   5449213PSO          အေးသူဇာဝင်း 9953898377
2024-02-12 00:00:00  Open   5443515QUR          အချစ်ခါးခါး 9786663605
```

This is df2

```
5071917VXV
5072021JEY
5072117RUL
5071820LOB
```

I want to concatenate like this

```
AWB/AWBCreated Date  Status AWB/AWB Number  AWB/Sender/Name AWB/Sender/Mobile
2024-02-13 00:00:00  Open   5449151CGT          phoe la pyae    9797116597
2024-02-13 00:00:00  Open   5449127AVE          Zin Lin *** 9441450256
2024-02-13 00:00:00  Open   5449213PSO          အေးသူဇာဝင်း 9953898377
2024-02-12 00:00:00  Open   5443515QUR          အချစ်ခါးခါး 9786663605

                            5071917VXV
                            5072021JEY
                            5072117RUL
                            5071820LOB
```

please give me pandas code

```
I try this.
df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=True)
```

but the resul is this.

```
AWB/AWBCreated Date  Status AWB/AWB Number  AWB/Sender/Name AWB/Sender/Mobile   AWB/AWB Number
2024-02-13 00:00:00  Open   5449151CGT          phoe la pyae    9797116597          5071917VXV
2024-02-13 00:00:00  Open   5449127AVE          Zin Lin *** 9441450256          5072021JEY      
2024-02-13 00:00:00  Open   5449213PSO          အေးသူဇာဝင်း 9953898377          5072117RUL
2024-02-12 00:00:00  Open   5443515QUR          အချစ်ခါးခါး 9786663605          5071820LOB
```

Comment: Your code should give the expected output. For a new column `df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=True, axis=1)`

Comment: df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=True, axis=1)
this code does not work .
this df3 result is below, which I don't want. 
AWB/AWBCreated Date  Status AWB/AWB Number  AWB/Sender/Name AWB/Sender/Mobile   AWB/AWB Number
2024-02-13   Open   5449151CGT          phoe la     9797116597          5071917VXV
2024-02-13   Open   5449127AVE          Zin Lin  9441450256          5072021JEY      
2024-02-13   Open   5449213PSO          အေးသူဇာဝင်း 9953898377          5072117RUL
2024-02-12   Open   5443515QUR          အချစ် 9786663605          5071820LOB

Comment: Please provide [reproducible DataFrame objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) in your question to demonstrate how this fails.